# Find a function definition for a specific function call with Clang

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, libclang

I'm trying to build a small program with *libclang* which retrieves the definition of a function/method for a specific function call.

For instance, I have the following `main.cpp`:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = add(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to call my program in such way:

```
./find_definition main.cpp add
```

and I would like it to return:

```
Definition of add in main.cpp:1 - int add(int x, int y)
```

I've read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037538/libclang-api-to-get-function-definitions-defined-in-a-different-file) SO question that `clang_getCursorUSR()` might help me and so far, I've got that code:

```
#include <clang-c/Index.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

CXChildVisitResult visitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor /* parent */, CXClientData clientData)
{
    CXSourceLocation location = clang_getCursorLocation(cursor);
    if(clang_Location_isFromMainFile(location) == 0)
    {
        // Continue the cursor traversal with the next sibling of the cursor just visited, without visiting its children.
        return CXChildVisit_Continue;
    }

    CXCursorKind cursorKind     = clang_getCursorKind(cursor);
    CXString     cursorSpelling = clang_getCursorSpelling(cursor);

    if (cursorKind == CXCursor_CallExpr && clang_getCString(cursorSpelling) == "add") {
        CXString cursorUsr = clang_getCursorUSR(cursor);
        std::cout << "Cursor USR is " << clang_getCString(cursorUsr) << std::endl;
        clang_disposeString(cursorUsr);
    }

    clang_disposeString(cursorSpelling);

    // Visit children nodes
    unsigned int curLevel  = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(clientData));
    unsigned int nextLevel = curLevel + 1;

    clang_visitChildren(cursor, visitor, &nextLevel);

    return CXChildVisit_Continue;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    return -1;

    CXIndex           index = clang_createIndex(0, 1);
    CXTranslationUnit tu    = clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile(index, argv[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if(!tu)
    {
        std::cout << "TU not found! Aborting...";
        return -1;
    }

    CXCursor rootCursor  = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(tu);

    unsigned int treeLevel = 0;

    clang_visitChildren(rootCursor, visitor, &treeLevel);

    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(tu);
    clang_disposeIndex(index);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it over my `main.cpp`, it prints only:

```
Cursor USR is
```

but I don't get any additional information.

Comment: It seems like an overkill to me, won't smart regex catch any (and only) function definition? I know C++ isn't regular language, but in this case it may be way to go.

Comment: In that simple example, regex might do but I actually have to use this on a bigger codebase and to interact with function definitions later on so I guess I'm forced to use *libclang*

Answer (score 0):

i think if your function definition is in the same file you can use the callexpr matcher to get the calling site. then use getDirectCallee to get the FunctionDecl. On the FunctionDecl you can invoke the getBody

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I’ll try it ASAP. And what if the definition is in another file?

Comment: I am not sure of the exact solution. I had done the following earlier. There may be a cleaner solution though. If its in a different, you need to parse that file as well and create a map of function definitions and their respective calls on your own. (this mapping aspect, i am not sure if clang provides any way to do)